# How does DRF turn off CSRF-token check for JWT-based authentication?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm using Django Rest Framework with [JWT as authentication mechanism](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/). As far as I've understood, using JWT authentication makes the CSRF-token check not necessary as long as the token is not stored in a cookie.

However, checking the `django-rest-framework-jwt` code and the Django `CsrfViewMiddleware` I don't understand which part of the code turns off the CSRF-token check for JWT-based authentication.

Does somebody know and can point to the relevant parts of the code?

Comment: did you find answer if yes please help me i also facing same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF exemption happens in [`APIView.as_view`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0148a9f8dac6730981f4a3d666d8def4570fdae0/rest_framework/views.py#L144) provided by Django REST Framework.

Comment: Note: As the comment indicates, the CSRF Django automatic validation is deactivated for all views and checked explicitly only for `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication`: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L129